# Как "контрибутить" в опен сорс? Андроид

Tags: android

Я жуниор андроид разработчик, Мне сказали что можно практиковатся "контрибутя" в опен сорс. Только я ничего не могу найти. Подскажите пожалуйста как вы это делаете?

Comment: https://www.alexeykopytko.com/2018/github-contributor-guide/ 
статья на эту тему. Если же Вы не можете найти проект, в который можно было бы контрибьютить, то это можно сделать просто просмотрев существующие проекты на том же GitHub

Comment: если ты не знаешь что это такое, то тебе это делать еще рано

Comment: есть нормальная инструкция https://opensource.guide/how-to-contribute/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Подозреваю, что большинство контрибьюторов в open source пришли просто исправив баг, который мешал им самим, или добавив функциональность, которой им не хватало, в приложение/библиотеку используемую каждый день.